# Type '(close: () => void) => ReactElement' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-tsx

I am trying to use @Reactjs-popup following this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/k2x7l5jy27) but in TypeScript, and when I access `close` function it shows this error.

```
Type '(close: () => void) => ReactElement' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
```

Original code(.js):

```js
    <Popup
      modal
      overlayStyle={{ background: "rgba(255,255,255,0.98" }}
      contentStyle={contentStyle}
      closeOnDocumentClick={false}
      trigger={open => <BurgerIcon open={open} />}
    >
      {close => <Menu close={close} />}
    </Popup>
```

My Code(.tsx):

```js
        <Popup
            modal
            overlayStyle={{ background: "rgba(255,255,255,0.98" }}
            contentStyle={contentStyle}
            closeOnDocumentClick
            trigger={(open: boolean): ReactElement => <BurgerIcon open={open} />}
        >
            {(close: () => void): ReactElement => <Menu close={close} />}
        </Popup>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The types for this library are incomplete.

It looks like [this line](https://github.com/yjose/reactjs-popup/blob/master/src/types.tsx#L33) that would allow a function to be used as `children` is commented out.

```
  children: React.ReactNode;

  //| ((close: () => void, isOpen: boolean) => React.ReactNode);
```

I'm assuming it was difficult to type properly and the library author gave up.

In addition, this library has not been changed in 2 years, and has this banner on the top:

[image]

To me, these would be clues that it may be best to choose a different library.